# What is the function of these Armature repair stations in Mass Effect?

Tags: mass-effect

In Mass Effect when Shepard is on Ilos he can find two Armature repair stations like this:

[image]

I'm wondering whether they serve some purpose or not? If I use them they get activated but nothing else happens. I can progress with the game either way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hacking the Armature repair stations will turn the Armatures on the lower level in Ilos before you unlock the main gate to pursue Saren to turn against the Geth. This, especially on higher difficulties, will make clearing out the Geth on the way to the console that unlocks the main gate much easier both by destroying Geth and drawing their fire away from you.

Hacking all of these stations can result in as many as four Geth Armatures turning on their allies.

Destroying the Armatures before hacking these terminals results in the terminals having no effect.

Comment: This is my 3rd playthrough and now I remember seeing Armatures attacking the geth. Now I understand thanks!